# Modx - сайт открывается только через ресурсы

Tags: сервер, modx, hosting, control-panel

Доброго всем вечера. Сидел я в админке modx, настраивал Контроль доступа по видео в [ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij1yGnATSZg&t=5579s)

Потом создал статический ресурс с pdf файлом, далее решил зайти через инкогнито на сайт, посмотреть, как он выглядит. и.. опа, сайт не грузит, выводит:

> "Service unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your
>   request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
>   again later."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что странно: в админку modx cms он заходит (отсюда сделал вывод, что дело не в хостинге, а что-то пошло не так в админ панели). А если во вкладке Ресурсы ПКМ-ом нажать на ресурс -> просмотреть, то сайт открывается и все грузит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт: https://ScArtProject.ru - сюда не заходит
Ссылка: https://ScArtProject.ru/manager/ - сюда заходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я обнулил свой хостинг, залил сохранившийся бэкап, и сайт заработал. Менеджеров-то все равно надо добавить. Заново по видео, настроил контроль доступа, создал пользователей, создал статический ресурс для pdf файла и снова все по кругу - опять сайт не доступен. 
Писал в поддержку хостинга, говорят, мол на их стороне ошибок нет и перевели мой акк на другой хостинг. Но когда снова проделываю вышесказанное, сайт умирает

Помогите пожалуйста, разъясните - в чем может быть проблема?

p.s. Проверял на нескольких пк, браузерах и девайсах (смартфон, планш, лэптоп, дт) - везде не получается зайти.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У тебя из-за протокола не работает.. https не работает, а http работает.

Answer (score 1):

В общем нужно было правильно настроить .htaccess и в системных настройках меняем http на https, чистим кэш и uri обязательно. Можно ч-з ftp кэш тоже удалить и заходим на сайт